Heap vs Red-Black Tree
Why would we ever use a heap over a red-black tree?
Take a scenario where we want a min-heap. The time complexities of a mean-heap are as follows.
Peek: O(1) average/worst
Delete First: O(log(n)) average/worst
Delete Arbitrary: O(n) average/worst
Search: O(n) average/worst

Now let’s reimplement this with a red-black tree that caches the left-most element.
Peek: O(1) average/worst
Delete First: O(1) average / O(log(n)) worst
Delete Arbitrary: O(log(n)) average/worst
Search: O(log(n)) average/worst

This is using the fact that rebalancing a rb-tree is amortized O(1). If we maintained an element to node address hash map, we can even make arbitrary deletions in an rb-tree O(1) average.
I get that heaps are usually more memory efficient and have better cache locality, but does it make that much of a difference? Especially if your application commonly uses say the delete first operation.

To populate the data structure with  elements is cheaper with a heap: a heap can be constructed with O() time complexity, while a BST needs O(log). If you need search, then heap is not the right data structure.

"but does it make that much of a difference": why not benchmark this yourself?

What's a "mean-heap"?

"I get that heaps are usually more memory efficient and have better cache locality" - you've basically answered your question there already. Also you have looked at the complexities of only 4 operations, while there are many more that could be relevant (in particular construction, as mentioned by @trincot). "Especially if your application commonly uses say the delete first operation." - then that is specific to that particular application, but irrelevant for "why would we ever?".

Also, don't forget that big-O notation hides constants that may be significant in practice. For small n, O(n) may beat O(log n) depending on those hidden constants.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29548834/56778, which gives a whole lot of good detail.
