# Heap or Red-Black Tree?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, red-black-tree, binary-heap

I am willing to use a data structure as an overflow buffer of constant space. I want to have efficient insert but most importantly efficient removal of the min element. I was thinking of using a heap since I have O(log(n)) find_min() and log(n) insertion and deletion. On the other hand I know don't understand the advantage in comparison to a red-black tree  since it also has O(log(n)) insert and delete but and O(1) find min/max. And the advantage of sorted output (I do not care about that).

The question is related to:[Is a red-black tree my ideal data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508406/is-a-red-black-tree-my-ideal-data-structure)

Since I have both of the structures available from std::map and from boost::heap why should I prefer to use heap instead of the red-black tree?
Finally, using the red-black tree I have also O(log(n)) search time for an entry while for a heap the time is O(n) which is important since duplicates exist.

Comment: Consider a ring buffer.  Don't know if it's appropriate for your uses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heap vs Binary Search Tree (BST)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147242/heap-vs-binary-search-tree-bst)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is primarily in how you would use the structures.

- Binary heaps are very fast data structures for inserting values and retrieving the minimum value.  However, they don't support efficient searching or deletion of random values.
- Red/black trees are balanced binary search trees that support efficient insertion, deletion, lookup of arbitrary values, and (reasonably fast) find-minimum.  However, they have a lot of overhead compared to a binary heap.

If all you need is insertion, find-minimum, and remove-minimum, the binary heap is probably a superior choice because the overhead is lower and the runtime should be faster.  If you need to insert and remove arbitrary values or lookup arbitrary values, the red/black tree is probably the better choice.  As with all engineering, choosing the right data structure is all about tradeoffs.

Also, note that you can use `std::priority_queue` if you need a binary heap; you don't need to use Boost.  It's also not guaranteed that `std::map` is a red/black tree; it's probably some sort of balanced BST, but it could be balanced using some other algorithm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. In my data I have duplicates so I cant avoid find() which is expensive on a heap. On the other hand insert and erase are faster in a heap but logarithmic in the red-black tree. I guess the red-black tree is the right answer for this one.However, I have seen in a paper using a heap even if they have find() operations and thats why I am confused.

Comment: A heap is not a search data structure; you can, however, store the position of an element inside the heap, so at a later time you can change its priority (which will move the element up or down accordingly). Many sweep-line-based geometric algorithms require this kind of "find-and-update".

Comment: To add to what DanielKO said, I once saw a custom binary heap that maintained each item's index within the items themselves.  The creator was only interested in O(1) contains, which that enabled (`items[item.index] == item`), but you could also use it to greatly speed up other operations.

Answer (score 5):

A heap is easily implemented in contiguous memory, i.e. an array.  A red-black tree is typically constructed with a separate heap allocation for each node.  The red-black tree ends up accessing memory all over the heap for each tree traversal.  This is worst-case cache behavior.  Even though the algorithmic complexity of certain operations is the same for both structures, the constant overhead for the red-black tree is much higher.